# Restangular getList response should be array not object, getList not working with json

Tags: angularjs, json, codeigniter, response, restangular

I know this question has already been asked so many times before but I am not able to find out any good example which can solve my issue.

I am using Codeigniter Rest APIs for my project with AngularJS. This is my response

```
{"msg":"success","data":{"test":"1","test1":"2"}}
```

I am using Codeigniter method to send response in this way.

```
$data = array();
        $data['test']  = '1';
        $data['test1'] = '2';
        $this->response(array('msg' => 'success', 'data' => $data),200);
```

and this is AngularJS code

```
factory.create = function(){
        return Restangular.all('index.php/customer/getAll').getList().then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Please help me to understand and resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Your response is not that array. Isn't that clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below to receive result as array :

```
$data = array();
$data[]  = [ "label" => 'test1',"id" => 1];
$data[]  = [ "label" => 'test2',"id" => 2];
$this->response(array('msg' => 'success', 'data' => $data),200);
```

Comment: sorry, its giving the same error. o/p in console is {"msg":"success","data":[{"label":"test1","id":1},{"label":"test2","id":2}]}